# C++ nonconst-const reference function overloading

Tags: c++, g++, pass-by-reference, lvalue, rvalue

In the following code:

```
int foo(const int& f) //version 1
{
    int g = f;
    return int(foo(g)); // calls itself, turning into SO
}

int& foo(int& f) //version 2
{
    f *= -1;
    return f;
}

int main()
{
    int f = 11;
    cout << foo(f) << endl;
    cout << foo(22) << endl;
}
```

The first cout prints -11 as expected; f is a *lvalue*, so it binds to the second version of *foo* (although it could bind to 1st version as well, the 2nd version it's a better match).

The second call of `foo` is using a rvalue as parameter, so the only viable version of `foo` is the first one. So far, so good. Inside the first version of `foo`, I made a copy of the parameter so I could call the second version (with a *lvalue*) and return a copy of it after the call of the second version of `foo`. The thing is this will turn into a stack overflow; still the first version of `foo` will be called.

Could someone please explain to me why this happens? I would expect that `g` inside the first version of `foo` to bind to the second version of `foo` when passed as parameter.

Comment: How would the first `foo` know about the second `foo`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's simple really - `foo` at that point only means `foo(const int& f)`. There's no second choice. Not yet. Switch up the definitions. Or separate them:

```
int foo(const int& f);
int& foo(int& f);

int main()
{
    int f = 11;
    cout << foo(f) << endl;
    cout << foo(22) << endl;
}


int foo(const int& f) //version 1
{
    int g = f;
    return int(foo(g)); // calls itself, turning into SO
}

int& foo(int& f) //version 2
{
    f *= -1;
    return f;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The first declaration of foo has no idea about the existence of the second one. Try this:

```
int foo(int& f);
int foo(const int& f) //version 1
{
    int g = f;
    return int(foo(g)); // calls itself, turning into SO
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When the compiler reaches the line:

```
return int(foo(g))
```

It doesn't know about your overloaded version 2. Add prototype declarations to the top of the file:

```
int foo(const int& f);
int& foo(int& f);
```

This way the compiler will know about the existence of version 2 and can consider it when working out whith `foo` to call.